# Will we have to die twice?

Tags: death, day-of-judgement

As far as I am concerned, at the time of Qyamah people will rise from the graves  and other people will see them but ultimately everyone will be destroyed. So, the people who rise from their graves will they die again and thus ultimately end up diying or tasting death twice?

Answer (score -2):

First of all look at the following verse:

> قَالُوا رَبَّنَا أَمَتَّنَا اثْنَتَيْنِ وَأَحْيَيْتَنَا اثْنَتَيْنِ
>   فَاعْتَرَفْنَا بِذُنُوبِنَا فَهَلْ إِلَىٰ خُرُوجٍ مِّن سَبِيلٍ ﴿١١
>
> They will say, "Our Lord, You made us lifeless twice and gave us life
>   twice, and we have confessed our sins. So is there to an exit any
>   way?" (11)

As well as the mentioned verse, it is said from Allameh-Tabatabae علامه طباطبائی  as a Shia scholar (by helping of other verses): The human when entered the Barzakh, would be dead in comparison with the world and would be alive in compassion with Barzakh. And when he transferred (went) to Qiamat-al-Kobra, he would be dead in comparison to Barzakh and would be alive than Qiamat-al-Kobrah.

---

**Reference:**

[www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=95276)

[http://tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/40:11)

Comment: I meant about the rising from graves which I described in the description....

Comment: Your answer was kind of irrelevent